# Mongoose not saving some values when passed to constructor

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following code:

```
app.get('/checkout', function (req, res, next) {
  var checkout = new Checkouts();
  checkout.itemCode = req.query.itemCode;
  checkout.showDate = req.query.showDate;
  checkout.expectedReturn = req.query.expectedReturn
}
```

I want to create a more compact version of this code, by passing in the values into the constructor.  For some reason when I try this code:

```
app.get('/checkout', function (req, res, next) {
  var checkout = new Checkouts({
      itemCode: req.query.itemCode,
      showDate: req.query.showDate,
      expectedReturn: req.query.expectedReturn
  });
}
```

Some of the values, specifically `itemCode` is always skipped (left as a blank object in my database) even though it is in the `req.query`. (I.e. the top code example works with every item even though the `req` are identical.

Any idea why this is?

**Here is the Checkout Schema**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var CheckInSchema = require('./checkins');

var checkoutSchema = new Schema({
  itemCode: {
    category: String
  },
  showDate: {
    category: String
  },
  expectedReturn: {
    type: Date
  }
});

var CheckOuts = mongoose.model('CheckOuts', checkoutSchema);

module.exports = CheckOuts;
```

Here is the **SERVER SIDE CODE**

```
router.get('/checkout', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.query);
  console.log(typeof req.query.itemCode);

  var checkout = new CheckOuts({
    itemCode: req.query.itemCode,
    showDate: req.query.showDate,
    expectedReturn: req.query.expectedReturn
  });
```

Which logs:

```
{ 
  expectedReturn: '0388-03-04T08:00:00.000Z',
  itemCode: '102012', //Note that item code is here as a string
  showDate: '0198-05-05T07:00:00.000Z'
  }
string // Note that item code is a string and present
{ __v: 0,
  expectedReturn: Fri Mar 04 388 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST),
  _id: 54e39a909188007dd0ef683d,
  showDate: {},  // Show date is blank
  itemCode: {}  // So is item code
}
```

Comment: Please provide us your schema. What is the dataType of the itemCode in your schema? And what's the dataType in req.query.itemCode?

Comment: @mosquito87, it is now shown.

Comment: Shouldn't `category:` be `type:` in your schema?

Comment: I think that is the answer....I am not sure what the difference is.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass an Object, try this:

```
app.get('/checkout', function (req, res, next) {
  var checkout = new Checkouts({
      itemCode: req.query.itemCode,
      showDate: req.query.showDate,
      expectedReturn: req.query.expectedReturn
  });
}
```

Comment: How is this any different than my second example? I.e. the one that does not work?

Comment: you use assignment operator instead of colons

Answer (score 0):

Your schema has to be:

```
var checkoutSchema = new Schema({
    itemCode: String,
    showDate: String,
    expectedReturn: Date
});
```

I'm not sure about `showDate`. What does that field mean? I guess the type should be `Boolean`. See the mongoose documentation @ http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html for more information.